# Exception for when multiple files not found?

Tags: c#, linq, exception, .net-4.0

Is there an exception that I can use for when there are one or more files not found?

I'm doing this: `filePaths.Where(file => !file.Exists);` and I need to throw some kind of FilesNotFound exception. Do I need to inherit from Exception and make my own exception class?

I'm using C# .NET 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should should inherit from [System.IO.IOException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception.aspx) and expose a Files property on it.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a [FileNotFoundException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception.aspx) in .NET that you can use if you didn't want to write your own. It only relates to one file though, but you could always inherit it and write a `FilesNotFoundException` to cater for more than one file